# Mouse click/move simulation on a "specific window"

Tags: c++, winapi, sendmessage

This is the part of my code that is supposed to implement the mouse simulation:

```
SendMessage(winHandle, WM_MOUSEMOVE, 0, MAKELPARAM(0, 0));
SendMessage(winHandle, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, 0, 0);
SendMessage(winHandle, WM_LBUTTONUP, 0, 0);
```

As you can see, i'm trying to make the mouse's cursor move to a the point (0, 0) of the specified window and perform a single click. But for some reason, the cursor doesn't move at all, and it just clicks on wherever it's currently in.
How can i fix that?

Comment: @JonathanPotter i already did, couldn't find what i'm looking for.

Comment: [WM_MOUSEMOVE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-mousemove) message is *Posted to a window when the cursor moves*. @RemyLebeau has answered some applicable way but if possible, use [Microsoft UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32) which *is an accessibility framework that enables Windows applications to provide and consume programmatic information about user interfaces (UIs)*.

Comment: Sending a `WM_MOUSEMOVE` message is like photoshopping a parcel tracking report, and expecting it to physically move the delivery truck to your front door. That's not how things work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WM_MOUSEMOVE` doesn't actually move the cursor, it just notifies the window that a movement had occurred. To actually move the cursor, use `SetCursorPos()` or `SendInput()` instead. Use `ClientToScreen()` or `MapWindowPoints()` to convert the desired client coordinates into screen coordinates to then move to.